# Angular 4 Populate Query Parameters Dynamically

Tags: angular, rest, http, url-parameters

Goal is to produce the url like below:

```
/powerPlants?onlyActive=true&page=1
```

I have the following function in my Typescript!

```
allPowerPlants(config: PowerPlantListConfig): Observable<PowerPlant[]> {
    // Convert any filters over to Angular's URLSearchParams
    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    Object.keys(config.filters)
      .forEach((key) => {
        params.set(key, config.filters[key]);
      });

    return this.apiService
      .get('/powerPlants'),
      .map(data => data);
  }
```

Any suggestions on how I could produce this dynamic url from the incoming config which is PowerPlantListConfig

The PowerPlantListConfig is as below:

```
export class PowerPlantListConfig {
  type = 'all';

  filters: {
    page?: number,
    onlyActive?: boolean
  } = {};
}
```

EDIT: As a quick and dirty try, this is what I tried (by hard coding values)

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
makeRequest(): void {

    const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    params.set('onlyActive', 'false');
    params.set('page', '1');
    this.loading = true;
     this.http.request('http://localhost:9000/powerPlants', {params: params})
    // this.http.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res.json()));
      this.data = JSON.stringify(res.json());
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
```

But that seems not to take effect as I see the URL without the URL parameters getting called!

Comment: Please use [tag:angular] for version 2+, and [tag:angularjs] for version 1.x (I already retagged this question). Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Would you also be able to help me out with my problem?

Comment: No, sorry. I'm unfamiliar with angular 4

Comment: I'm predominantly a backend developer and to me it is like saying I don't know Scala 2.12 as I only know Scala 2.11! No offence meant, but that is what it is programming with Angular. It keeps changing so drastically that you have to learn it from the start with every new version!

Comment: how do you import `URLSearchParams`?

Comment: True for v1 -> 2, Not true for v2 -> v4. They are trying to keep Angular updated with current standards so as not to require a major rewrite again. So let's hope. :-)

Comment: I do not import it at all!

Comment: I have edited my post with the imports that I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a Small Example of the new HttpClientModule

```
import {HttpParams} from "@angular/common/http";

const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('orderBy', '"$key"')
    .set('limitToFirst', "1");

this.courses$ = this.http
    .get("/courses.json", {params})
    .do(console.log)
    .map(data => _.values(data))
```

You can also go for the New HttpClientModule and use the `HttpParams` for the same . Gist for the [same](https://gist.github.com/rahulrsingh09/271aaff4cb134685ed7a62197670938c)

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion and hint from [Maxim Koretskyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2545680/maxim-koretskyi)

I had to import the URLSearchParams as:

```
import {Http, URLSearchParams, Response} from '@angular/http';
```

But I would have been happy if my Webstorm IDE did this for me!

Comment: Try VS Code! It will add your missing references for you. :-)

Comment: That is from Microsoft? I'm allergic to anything from Microsoft!

Comment: Then I hope you are not using Observables ... because they come from Microsoft as well. :-) https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReactiveExtensionsRxIsNowOpenSource.aspx as did TypeScript!

Comment: I'm predominantly a backend mule and I do a lot of Scala and Haskell. I love to do Javascript with ScalaJS and yes I have used Rx on Scala but I use the Monix library - which is infact inspired by Rx.NET

Comment: @sparkr, it doesn't add import reference because it thinks [its NodeJS class](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams). You have to always double check what you  import when working with Http classes as many of them resemble NodeJS classes and you may end up with unexpected behavior

Comment: Thanks mate for the suggestion and the help!